# django-registration disable activation

Tags: django, django-registration

Is there a setting in django-registration to disable the activation? Preferably, the e-mail would still be send with something like: `Thanks for your registration.`

1. Is it possible to deactivate the required account activation and how?
2. Is it still possible to send the activation e-mail but without the verification requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [`simple` backend](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/27bccd108cdef30dc0a91ed1968be17bb1e60da4/registration/backends/simple/__init__.py?at=default).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question, but in case someone was still looking for a solution,
here is one option based on the specific 'user_activated' signal provided by django-registration.

As required by the original question, the activation is revoked silently, and
the user isn't aware of this.

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from registration.signals import user_activated


def remove_user_activation(user):
    """
    Replace with specific app logic
    """
    return True


@receiver(user_activated)
def on_user_activated(sender, **kwargs):
    """
    Revoke activation to robot users
    """

    user = kwargs['user']

    if remove_user_activation(user):
        if user.is_active:
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
```